# Why does using this index key for my simple mysql query increase query time so much?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand the massive difference in query time between the following two queries on my InnoDB table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   db_telemetry.monitor_data 
WHERE  monitor_id = 6 
       AND created_at > '2019/11/14' 
       AND created_at < '2019/11/29';
```

4317 rows returned in 37.672s

```
SELECT * 
FROM   db_telemetry.monitor_data USE INDEX(ix_monitor_data_created_at) 
WHERE  monitor_id = 6 
       AND created_at > '2019/11/14' 
       AND created_at < '2019/11/29';
```

4317 rows returned in 0.110s

According to `EXPLAIN` the optimizer in the first (slow) query is choosing `monitor_id` for its index key. From what I've read this is strange because `monitor_id` has comparatively low cardinality (see below)

My table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE monitor_data

CREATE TABLE `monitor_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `monitor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vbattery` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rssi` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecio` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `tboard` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `txbytes` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rxbytes` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `satelite_count` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `gps_fix` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `drive_space_remaining` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `other` text,
  `daq_reachable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monitor_reachable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clock_reset_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_key` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_temp` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `vin` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `webrelay_reachable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daq_current_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `webrelay_current_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`monitor_id`),
  KEY `monitor_id` (`monitor_id`),
  KEY `ix_monitor_data_site_key` (`site_key`),
  KEY `ix_monitor_data_created_at` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `monitor_data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`monitor_id`) REFERENCES `monitors` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10839466 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Its indexes:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM monitor_data

Table           Non_unique  Key_name                    Seq_in_index    Column_name  Cardinality
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
monitor_data    0           PRIMARY                     1               id           11311240               
monitor_data    0           PRIMARY                     2               monitor_id   11311240       
monitor_data    1           monitor_id                  1               monitor_id   110                
monitor_data    1           ix_monitor_data_site_key    1               site_key     28137          
monitor_data    1           ix_monitor_data_created_at  1               created_at   11311240           

Sub_part and Packed all NULL
Index_type all BTREE
Collation all 'A'
```

This is MySQL version 5.6.40 running on an AWS RDS t2.small instance with a 20GB general purpose SSD.

If I use only the `monitor_id` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   db_telemetry.monitor_data 
WHERE  monitor_id = 6;
```

274324 rows returned in 0.078s

If I use only the `created_at` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   db_telemetry.monitor_data 
WHERE  created_at > '2019/11/14' 
       AND created_at < '2019/11/29';
```

202976 rows returned in 0.109s

So, questions:

1. Why does the optimizer choose `monitor_id` by default for index, and is there a likely problem with my schema making `USE INDEX()` necessary?
2. Since in isolation both indexes reduce dataset to a similar # of
   rows why is the multi-condition query so much slower using `monitor_id` for
   index?

NOTE: I've observed for certain smaller date ranges that the optimizer flips over to picking `ix_monitor_data_created_at`

Comment: As well as formatted queries, I prefer SHOW CREATE TABLE; I just find both easier to comprehend. - And is this MyISAM? Why?

Comment: @Strawberry, It's InnoDB, and I updated the question

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @PeterHe Version 5.6.40

Comment: Before mysql 8.0, mysql innodb does not persist the statistics. It has only in memory statistics built in runtime since server starts so it can be very inaccurate if your data skewed. Inaccurate statistics will lead to sub-optimal execution plans. In your case, using the index hint is not a problem. But if this is your important query and is used frequently, you may try to convert the index monitor_id to be a compound index to include the column create_at. mysql should use this index automatically for your query

Comment: Has something changed in MySQL? I cannot create this table using InnoDB?!?!

Comment: So, yeah, testing this in later versions of MySQL, it seems that you can currently create a multi-column PK with an AI in that position. But would you really want to? Wouldn't it be better to have a 'standalone' AI, and then a compound index on some combination of created_at and monitor_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`monitor_id`),
```

does not make sense when `id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Perhaps the *only* difference with `PRIMARY KEY(id)` is that you are allowing duplicate values for `id`.  (But you would have to explicitly set `id` to get a dup.)  Either way, the PK is 'clustered' with the data, and the data is ordered by `id`.

For the query, you need this composite index:

```
INDEX(monitor_id, created_at)
```

Why did the Optimizer pick the 'wrong' index?  A lot of possible reasons, but mostly because it does not have sufficient statistics.  Another possible reason for the wide difference in timings is ...

What order were the rows inserted into the table?  Presumably 'chronologically'?  That is, the rows for that date range are "near" each other, making the use of that index "fast".  Meanwhile, looking up by `monitor_id` implies jumping all over the table.

My composite index defeats all the issues by dipping into the BTree for the index at (6, '2019/11/14'), then scanning forward, until exactly all the 4317 *index* rows are found.  Meanwhile, it reaches over into the data (via `id`) to get `SELECT *`.

Another issue...  You probably ran the 4 queries in the order shown, and starting with a 'cold' cache (the buffer_pool).  That is, the first query had the overhead of 4317 disk reads.  (Note:  that takes about 43.17 seconds on a HDD.)  Then the other `SELECTs` found all that cached.

So...  When runing timing test, run the query twice.